# Add new rows with identical value except for one column

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates, rows

I am still pretty new to SQL and I don't know whether it is possible.
So I have this flight trip table and I need to count how many flights per route. The problem is there is RoundTrip flight that makes it harder to count the way back flight. The table is like this:

| source_id | destination_id | date | trip_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUH | MAN | 2017-01-01 | RoundTrip |
| LHR | CDG | 2017-05-12 | OneWay |
| DXB | BHX | 2017-12-20 | Roundtrip |

All I want is turn the table into:

| source_id | destination_id | date | trip_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUH | MAN | 2017-01-01 | RoundTrip |
| MAN | AUH | 2017-01-01 | RoundTrip |
| LHR | CDG | 2017-05-12 | OneWay |
| DXB | BHX | 2017-12-20 | Roundtrip |
| BHX | DXB | 2017-12-20 | Roundtrip |

Therefore I can create a new column later that combine source_id and destination_id, then groupby it to count the total trip per route.

Thank you before for your kind effort to answer this !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `insert`:

```
insert into t (source_id, destination_id, date, trip_type)
    select destination_id, source_id, date, trip_type
    from t
    where trip_type = 'Roundtrip';
```

Note:  If there is the possibility of the rows already in the table and you want to avoid duplicates, you can add a `not exists` clause:

```
insert into t (source_id, destination_id, date, trip_type)
    select destination_id, source_id, date, trip_type
    from t
    where trip_type = 'Roundtrip' and
          not exists (select 1
                      from t t2
                      where t2.trip_type = t.trip_type and
                            t2.date = t.date and
                            t2.destination_id = t.source_id and
                            t2.source_id = t.destination_id
                     );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works perfectly and I got the desired result.